# Finding the pattern in desired output

Tags: java

This might be extremely elementary to some but I cant seem to wrap my head around it. The directions of an assignment I have are:

> Only one place should be changed.
> Instead of printing
>
> ```
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
> ```
>
> make it print:
>
> ```
> 99, 80, 63, 48, 35, 24, 15, 8, 3, 0
> ```

Code:

```
public class Lab9
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int counter;
        counter=1; // do not change this line
        while(counter<=10) // do not change this line
        {
            System.out.println(counter); // do change this line
            counter=counter+1; // do not change this line
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to add new lines in between?

Comment: I think the only way it might be able to work is with new lines in between. It wasn't specified though.

Comment: If not, change `System.exit(0)` to `System.out.println("99\n80\n63\n48\n35\n24\n15\n8\n3\n0")`. *Good enough for the demo, lol*

Comment: Look at the pattern in the numbers: 99-80=19; 80-63=17; 63-48=15; etc... You need to include that idea in the code.

Comment: There is a pattern here from the end to the beginning. The difference between the numbers are as such: 3, 5, 7, 9, ...

Comment: The pattern subtracts each term in the order -19 -17 -15 etc. I just have no idea how to translate that into code.

Comment: Let's start by thinking about the pattern "19, 17, 15, ...". These look like odd numbers to me. So let's back up a step further. Can you change your code to print out odd numbers starting at 1?

Comment: There are two cool solutions below, though I like @IanMc better as it explains the pattern clearly.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to come up with the algorithm for that number sequence, but haven't learned `for` loops yet? Hmmm..... *<confused>*

Answer (score 9):

The pattern is one less than the square of counter (in reverse order)

```
public class Lab9{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int counter;
        counter=1; // do not change this line
        while(counter<=10) // do not change this line
        {
            System.out.println((11-counter)*(11-counter)-1); // do change this line
            counter=counter+1; // do not change this line
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work the best with what I'm given in the directions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but I think you just have to find the pattern.

You could try something like this:

```
public class Lab9{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int counter;
        counter=1; // do not change this line
        while(counter<=10) // do not change this line
        {
            System.out.println((12-counter)*(10-counter)); // changed
            counter=counter+1; // do not change this line
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```